# Trouble collapsing messages with jquery and css

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to expand messages when clicked on and collapse them when a particular element is clicked. I am using two different classes, one for when the element is collapsed and another for when the whole message is to be shown.

**Problem:**
The elements expand when clicked as expected but when I click the collapse element nothing happens (the class doesn't change).

A simplified version of the html/jquery/css used  is shown below:

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="messages">
    <div class="collapsed_message">
      <!-- couple of other elements go here see jsfiddle-->
       <div class="message_content">
          Message goes here
       </div>
      <span class="collapse_bar">
        <span class="re_collapse">[collapse]</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.collapsed_message{
    overflow:hidden;

}
.entire_message{
  // other styling here
}
```

javascript/jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".collapsed_message").click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('entire_message').removeClass("collapsed_message");
});
$(".re_collapse").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().parent().addClass("collapsed_message").removeClass('entire_message');
});
});
```

For a full copy of the code see jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8vDZb/

Comment: You added a listener: `$(".re_collapse").click(function () {` but the class `.re-collapse` never exists. Therefor, that listen is never active. Also, you have a small typo in the `<img />` tag. You don't close that tag. Use the `/>` to close `<img />` tags.

Comment: What do you mean the class .re_collapse never exsists? I am  looking at it in line 57 of the fiddle

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that - didn't see that. I was debugging your code a little bit, but it looks like @Dimitri Jorse has nailed it. Try adding some `console.log()` to your listeners and see when each is triggered. Check out: http://jsfiddle.net/8vDZb/2/

Comment: Thanks, console.log() looks like its going to be an invaluable tool for debugging!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I would suggest that you use a plugin such as [Jquery-ui Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/).

If you really want to know what is wrong here:

You have a listener on the `.collapsed_message` class. Once you click on this item, the **clicked** callback is called and the class is removed. However, the listener is still plugged, so when you click on **[collapse]**, it is called again because `.re_collapse` is contained within the `.collapsed_message` element.

Which mean that both callback are triggered.

Comment: Seems like you are right, @Dimitri Jorge. Check out the console log on this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8vDZb/2/
It explains it.